# unexpected results with intel primitive (when dividing by 1)

Tags: c++, intel-ipp

I'm using Intel Integrated Performance Primitives (v2019, 64bit) and I came across unexpected results.

When I run the following code

```
    std::cout << std::setprecision(20);
    const int N = 8;
    const std::vector<double> one(N, 1.0);
    std::vector<double> d(N,0.014058305571221497);
    
    std::cout << "before division by 1 : " << d[0] << std::endl;
    ippsDiv_64f_I(one.data(), d.data(), N);
    std::cout << "after division by 1 : " << d[0] << std::endl;
```

I get the following output :

```
before division by 1 : 0.014058305571221497293 
after division by 1 : 0.014058305571221500763
```

1/ How dividing by 1 can change the value ?

2/ For any value of N between 1 and 7, dividing by 1 has no effect. Only for N>7 I get this. How can it be that the result of a division of doubles depend on the size of my array ?

Could it be a bug ?

Comment: ***Could it be a bug ?*** My guess is its the same as 0.2 + 0.1 is not equal to 0.3: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: 0.2+0.1 may not be equal to 0.3, but it will always be equal to the same value.
x/1.0 can only be equal to x, moreover how can the size of the array affect the result?

Comment: `std::setprecision(20);` is more digits than `double` typically has.

Comment: the precision is irrelevant, what it shows is that the value changes after dividing by 1. when N>7.

Comment: If its beyond the precision than the extra digits are not even stored.

Comment: Look at the IPP source code. Does the `ippsDiv_64f_I()` function take a different code path when the size is 8 or greater?

Comment: Maybe when size > 7 then vectorization kicks in, which could explain the change.

Comment: What happens if you do usual (unoptimized) divisions by 1.0 ?

Comment: Does `IppStatus` result of `ippsDiv_64f_I` show anything interesting?

Comment: FWIW, I wasn't able to reproduce the effect with `-Ofast` (https://godbolt.org/z/4qo5jav5s). The interesting thing about this question is that, supposedly, the number 1.0, in particular, is exact in floating point.

Comment: Can you try the non-in-place version of the function? https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/download/intel-integrated-performance-primitives-developer-reference-volume-1-signal-processing.html , called `ippsDiv_64f`

Comment: Typically `double` can not represent 20 decimal digits. Rounding errors happen on simplest floating operations. Test the sample code with `double` instead of `float` : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/max_digits10

Comment: @Red.Wave , yes, but I think the OP is pointing out that the doubles do not have the same bit pattern, otherwise they would print the same digits.

Comment: To answer the various comments :

For those who don't know about Intel Integrated Performance Primitives : Intel provides dlls exposing arithmetical methods on arrays (with great perfromance), we don't have access to the source code, and my compiler flags have no impact....

IppStatus is 0, so no problem.

I tested ippsDiv_64f, it gave exact same strange results as the in-place version.

Yes N>7 might be the threshold for vectorization... but it doesn't explain the results.

Comment: I tested with v2022 and I got the same results

Comment: To further narrow down your problem, you can disable certain vector extensions using [ippSetCpuFeatures](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/ipp/developer-guide-reference/2021-10/setcpufeatures.html), e.g.by calling `ippSetCpuFeatures(ippCPUID_MMX | ippCPUID_SSE | ippCPUID_SSE2)`.

Comment: @alfC can you locate the 1st differing digit? Compare that to `digits10` and `max_digits10`. Then print `nextafter` to get my point. Division also creates rounding errors.

Comment: @Red.Wave, I don't understand what I will get from it. https://godbolt.org/z/P6df4nqqd  . Of course, division produces rounding errors in general. The question is if division by (exact) 1.0 can introduce a rounding error or, for that matter, change the result. I think what happens is that the IPP library uses instructions that are not IEEE compliant.

Comment: @Red.Wave The difference is 2ulp. To say division creates rounding errors is naive. IEEE expects division to be within 0.5ulp. Therefore, this doesn't follow the expected/usual rules of floating point and it's a fair question as to what rules it does follow.

Comment: @Quxflux I tried and it didn't help. Even ippSetCpuFeatures(0) which enables MMX only has no impact. I've ran ippGetCpuFeatures before and after to confirm that SSE, SSE2, AXV2... were disabled.

Comment: I've raised my question with Intel. You can follow the discussion here : https://community.intel.com/t5/Intel-Integrated-Performance/unexpected-results-with-intel-primitive-when-dividing-by-1/m-p/1570166